# Why does sudo -i not set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR for the target user?

Tags: ssh, systemd, sudo, pam

`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is necessary for `systemctl --user` to work.

I have set up ubuntu server 16.04 to run systemd user sessions. Now, when trying to administer them, I find that when changin a user via `sudo -u $user -i` or even `su - $user`, the environment does not have `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` set, preventing `systemctl --user` from working. However, when I `ssh` straight into that user, it is set correctly.

If I understand the documentation correctly, this should be set by `libpam-systemd` when creating the user session. The user slice is started correctly, as the directory to which `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` should point(`/run/users/$uid`) exists. I'm hesitant to just hardcode it in, say, `.bash_profile`, because that seems hacky (albeit working), when pam should be taking care of it.

I can, of course, add `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to `env_keep` in `sudoers`, but that would just preserve the sudoing user's environment, which is not what I want. I want the *target* user's environment.

What I'm really wondering, though, is how come the session is set up correctly with `ssh`, but not with `su` or `sudo -i`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have replicated this issue on my Fedora 25 system.

I found a very suspicious condition in the source code.  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/f97b34a/src/login/pam_systemd.c#L439  It looks as if it was written with normal `sudo` in mind but not `sudo -u non-root-user`.

`machinectl shell --uid=non-root-user` worked as you requested.

`systemd-run` did not appear to work as desired, despite the reference to it in the machinectl documentation.

Some machinectl commands don't work if you have enabled SELinux at the moment, and these specific commands didn't work for me until I did `setenforce 0`.  However I'm in the middle of trying workarounds to get machinectl working as I want it to w.r.t SELinux, so it's possible my fiddling is what causes e.g. `machinectl shell` to timeout.

EDIT: I think this code was introduced after [this discussion](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2013-November/014742.html).  And apparently `su -` / `sudo -i` could be made to work, but no-one has implemented it (still).

Relevant commit is https://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/commit/?id=baae0358f349870544884e405e82e4be7d8add9f

Comment: In other words, PAM will not set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` for `sudo` sessions by design? I guess then me setting it in `~/.profile` isn't as hacky as I thought.

Comment: I don't want to say "by design" because I can't work out what the design is. Looking up sudo again, I see at least some builds/distributions preserve enough environment variables, that programs run as root can end up inflicting permission problems on the original user.  However this isn't a reason not to set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR corresponding to the _target_ user.

Comment: A related Q&A is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423632/ .

Answer (score 11):

> What I'm really wondering, though, is how come the session is set up correctly with ssh, but not with su or sudo -i?

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237

> Sorry, but "su" is a tool for changing user identities and very few
>   other process credentials temporarily. It's not a tool for opening a
>   completely new login session. A new login session has a very well
>   defined, pristine setup, not inheriting anything from any other
>   session, but this is really not the case for "su" uid changes: most of
>   the execution environment is inherited over, in numerous and
>   non-obvious ways, for example MAC contexts, audit contexts, cgroup
>   contexts, namespace contexts, scheduling, timer granularity, …
>
> if you want a full new session, use something like "machinectl login"
>   or "machinectl shell", which will actually get your a fully clean,
>   independent, detach environment, with no hidden process properties
>   leaking from where you call it into it.
>
> logind sessions are mostly bound to the audit session concept, and
>   audit sessions remain unaffected by "su", in fact they are defined to
>   be "sealed off", i.e. in a way that if a process entered a session
>   once, it will always stay with it, and so will its children, i.e. the
>   only way to get a new session is by forking off something off PID 1
>   (or something similar) that never has been part of a session.
>
> Or to say this differently: the stuff you invoke through "su" will
>   show up just fine in "loginctl", however, it remains part of your
>   original session, you logged in originally. You can verify that by
>   invoking "loginctl status" on the original session's ID (which you can
>   see through echo $XDG_SESSION_ID)

Comment: Note: `su --login` is explictly for opening a completely new login session

Comment: In short, a workaround for sudo not setting up a normal environment for the target user is to run `sudo machinectl shell [user]@.host`.

Answer (score 0):

I found running `sudo -E bash` properly saves `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

Comment: `-E, --preserve-env            preserve user environment when running command`.

Comment: This will wrongly copy the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` of the calling user.

Answer (score 0):

For those still wanting a `sudo -i` solution, you can install a pam module that creates `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.  An example is [pam_xdg](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code-pam_xdg.html).

Your distro is unlikely to have the `pam_xdg` package so to install this module you'll have to figure out how to do it yourself.  I use Gentoo and I created an ebuild that installs the module, but I'm yet to publish it as my overlay has plenty of dev commits that need finalization.  I'll update this answer once I uploaded it.

After properly installing the pam module, add the following line in `/etc/pam.d/sudo-i`:

```
session optional        pam_xdg.so
```

Specify `required` instead of `optional` if preferred.

Mind that this module tries to produce the default XDG values and `pam_systemd.so` might do different, so it's still hacky compared to just using `machinectl shell`.