# How to create / delete $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR at login / logoff

Tags: systemd, tmp, tmpfs, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

Today I was surprised to `ssh` into my box running Arch Linux and find that `/run/user/$(id -u)` didn't exist.

The [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) says:

> `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` defines the base directory relative to which user-specific non-essential runtime files and other file objects (such as sockets, named pipes, ...) should be stored. The directory MUST be owned by the user, and he MUST be the only one having read and write access to it. Its Unix access mode MUST be `0700`.
>
> The lifetime of the directory MUST be bound to the user being logged in. It MUST be created when the user first logs in and if the user fully logs out the directory MUST be removed. If the user logs in more than once he should get pointed to the same directory, and it is mandatory that the directory continues to exist from his first login to his last logout on the system, and not removed in between. Files in the directory MUST not survive reboot or a full logout/login cycle.

On a `systemd` box, is `/run/user/$(id -u)` the preferred place for `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (even if it needs to be created?)

If not, what's best practice for creating `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`?

How do I ensure that that the directory is deleted only when I have "fully" logged out?

(Does "fully" mean that mean all processes created by login shells have exited? How to check for that?)

Answer (score 8):

The `/run/user/N` directory, the `user@N` service, and the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable are managed by a systemd-specific Pluggable Authentication Module and the `logind` service.  On first log-on they create the directory, create the filesystem mounted there, and start the service; and on last log-off they stop the service, unmount the filesystem, and remove the directory.  This behaviour changes when systemd's `linger` option is set for the account.

Other systems operate differently.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017). [`pam_systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html). *systemd manual pages*. Freedesktop.org.
- [Why does sudo -i not set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR for the target user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346841/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[Per-user system services](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/per-user-system-services.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386658/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434647/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423648/5132

Comment: Thanks - I'm using `mosh`, and your 2nd last link explains *why* the `/usr/run/N` directory is not created. 

However, my question is about working around this, eg manually creating the directory that `systemd` would otherwise create from a shell login script.

Answer (score -1):

#### Set / create `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` at login

- Use existing `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` if it is set.
- Else, use `systemd`'s `/run/user/$UID` if it exists
- Else, create and use `/tmp/$USER-runtime`

Check the ownership and permissions of `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

- Create and use `/tmp/"$USER"-runtime-XXXXXX` if permissions are not good.

```bash
if [ -z "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then  # It's not already set
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$UID  # Try systemd created path
  if [ ! -d "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then
    # systemd-created directory doesn't exist
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/$USER-runtime
    if [ ! -d "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" ]; then  # Doesn't already exist
      mkdir -m 0700 "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
    fi
  fi
fi
# Check dir has got the correct type, ownership, and permissions
if ! [[ -d "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" && -O "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" &&
    "$(stat -c '%a' "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR")" = 700 ]]; then
  echo "\$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: permissions problem with $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:" >&2
  ls -ld "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" >&2
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/"$USER"-runtime-XXXXXX)
  echo "Set \$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Where did you get this info? Can you add links to sources?