# Process "systemd --user" has a high cpu usage, how to disable it?

Tags: systemd, systemd-user

On some servers (running ubuntu 18.04) I have a process "systemd --user" that uses ~10% of the CPU in average. Only the root user needs to start services.

Is this process really needed and how can I disable it?

Comment: You can't disable it, it's really needed

Comment: Only you can tell us, with that little information in the question.  Do users run GUI desktops on these "servers"?  Do the users use audio?  Or CJKV input methods?

Comment: no GUI, no audio, no CJKV input methods

Answer (score 2):

You can revert to good 'ol [init](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/8/init) and remove [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), a new(ish) replacement which has replaced many of the traditional Linux `does one thing and does it well` apps.

Wikipedia gives a good overview of [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) and [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) as well as many relevant resources, which is good, for the subject can become controversial to some folks.

The (partisan) blog [Without Systemd](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) outlines [how to do it if you run Xubuntu 16.04](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_an_Ubuntu_Xenial_installation), but I would encourage much study and thought before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by disabling the `pam_systemd` PAM.
However, you also thereby lose the automatic setting of the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable, creation of a per-user runtime directory, and creation of certain control groups, as well, note.
You'll have to gauge how much of a loss this is.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423648/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477049/5132
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2017). [`pam_systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html). *systemd manual pages*. Freedesktop.org.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this commands to disable it:

```
systemctl mask systemd-logind.service
pam-auth-update
```