# Run services as user without X (systemctl)

Tags: services, sshd, non-root-user, d-bus, systemctl

I have a small server running a minimal centos8.
I need to create services as a user and would like to use systemctl to do so.
I found I can use systemctl --user to create services without root permission, but any of those commands result in:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

After a preliminary Google search I found that the culprit is the absence of XDG_ env variables, after adding them manually as in the exports:

```
$ export -p | grep XDG
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="328295"
```

I couldn't run systemctl --user anyway, because /run/user/ is empty I guess.

```
$ systemctl status dbus
● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-01-13 14:26:04 GMT; 5h 43min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 332 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 26213)
   Memory: 3.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─332 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile -->
```

dbus seems to be running fine the only anomaly I found was:

```
$ loginctl session-status
328295 - server (1000)
           Since: Wed 2021-01-13 20:00:44 GMT; 10min ago
          Leader: 29745 (sshd)
          Remote: #############
         Service: sshd; type tty; class user
           State: active
            Unit: session-328295.scope
                  ├─29745 sshd: server [priv]
                  ├─29747 sshd: server@pts/0
                  ├─29748 -bash
                  ├─29790 loginctl session-status
                  └─29791 loginctl session-status
```

Which apprears as sshd is the init process for this session (probably creating problems with dbus?).
Just to check I tred:

```
$ dbus-monitor
Failed to open connection to session bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

Which seems unreasonable, I souldn't run a Xsession to have dbus working and access to services (anyway the server is headless and no x-server, moreover I run ssh from Windows).

At this point I think there is a problem with sshd, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does sudo -i not set XDG\_RUNTIME\_DIR for the target user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346841/why-does-sudo-i-not-set-xdg-runtime-dir-for-the-target-user)

Comment: The answer is not applicable, because they have the bus socket working (/run/user/$UID present), in my case I don't have it, but thanks to that thread I found that the offender is libpam-systemd https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/are-systemd-user-services-feasible-on-centos-4175580434/ seems to be correlated (answering that it is not possible in centos>=7)

Comment: I guess [loginctl enable-linger username](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) is only missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is `dbus-monitor --system`